# C#: Finding out if the last element in a List<string> is a carriage return?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

The logic I'm trying to use is this: 
1. Look at the last element of the List 
2. If it is a new line (carriage return), delete it

```
        int stringLength = mailingList.Count;

        if (mailingList[stringLength - 1].Equals(Environment.NewLine))
        {
            //mailingList.RemoveAt(stringLength - 1);
            txtOutput.Text = "exists";
        }

        else
        {
            txtOutput.Text = "does not exist";
        }
```

But no matter what I use, I'm not able to get this to work.
I've also tried using:

```
if (mailingList[stringLength - 1] == "\r\n")
```

And this doesn't work either.
From my output testing, I keep getting "does not exist".

How do I identify whether the last element is a new line or not?

Any help would be great!

Thanks,
Ray

Comment: your code looks right in both examples.  How do you know it's not right?  Is there an extra space in the last string?

Comment: `stringLength` is a very confusing/misleading name.

Comment: And please describe: "doesn't work" - is there (just) a newline in the last element?

Comment: Is it important that you find out if the element is a carriage return or could you do something else like mailingList[stringLength - 1].Trim() == string.Empty, or even better, .Trim() whatever is getting converted into this list?

Comment: Good question, agentj. I'm using a RichTextBox and I enter a bunch of numbers like this:
1
2
3
-- this is where I deliberately hit the return key to force a newline.

I'm thinking that this would result in a newline, right?

Comment: @Ray Not when you are getting the lines only. A line can never be Environment.NewLine

Comment: What *is* the last value?  Is it `""`?

Comment: @Ray: so you're only _assuming_ the last element is a newline. And it's so easy to find out. Always check the things you're so sure about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, then the last element probably isn't a new line.

How to you get the lines? 
Do you split a textbox? Then you won't get new lines, you will get an empty string. 
Then you should do something like:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mailingList.LastOrDefault())
```

What you likely should do before you take out the lines is to [Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx) the textbox text.

Comment: Thanks, Oskar. I didn't realize it would be as simple as not realizing that the last character wouldn't be a newline. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ

```
mailingList.LastOrDefault() == Environment.NewLine
```

this will cover the case if there are no elements in the list.

Comment: -1 The problem is not that he is not getting the last element rather that it isn't a NewLine

Comment: @Oskar I agree that his problem is likely that the last element isn't a new line, but his question is specifically "How do I identify whether the last element is a new line or not?".

Comment: true, I removed the downvote. But still sometimes you have to see what he is really asking, not what he is writing

Answer (score 0):

Some systems use only `\n` for newline, some even use only `\r`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: Well, Environment.NewLine takes that into account

Comment: true, but perhaps his strings come from outside of the current environment and thus are not identified

Comment: True as well, but unlikely given the context

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add(Environment.NewLine);
if (list[0].Equals(Environment.NewLine))
    System.Console.WriteLine("found newline");
```

prints the text "found newline" to the console.  Therefore I can only conclude that your list does not contain a newline in the last item.

We can only guess why that is because we can't see your code that populates the list.